# if li list is higher than UL than strech ul width

Tags: html, css

I need to create an LI list where will be Images shown, if the LI list height is not higher than the UL list , it should be shown in one row.

IF the height of the LI list is is bigger than the UL list than it should put them in two colones.
here is the fiddle im using [Fidle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mfh4223r/), but with float: left , it automatticly aligns the second LI in the left (instead it should go under the first LI, if there is no more space in the UL , than it should jump on a new row ).

Here is an image for better explanation:|

[image]

Comment: You have to use javascript or jquery for achieving that.

Comment: Possible with fixed width images and flexbox columns I suppose but more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

`flexbox` can do that with some constraints such as a height of the `ul` is required to be fixed in order to force the wrapping.

There are still bugs in Chrome regarding column wrapping in flexbox but, for what it's worth.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #c0ffee;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```